# SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup method throws Thread was being aborted error when SPGroup Name is passed

Tags: c#, multithreading, sharepoint-2010

I am getting 'Thread was being aborted - Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack' error when I use '`SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup`' method.

```
   bool bReachedMaxCount = false;
    SPPrincipalInfo[] _spPrincInfoColl = SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup(web, groupName, Int32.MaxValue - 1, out bReachedMaxCount);
```

We have both SharePoint groups (SPGroup) & Active Directory groups in our site.

I am checking if logged in user has access to the group name that I am passing here as 'groupName'.

Code works without any error when I pass 'domain name' as 'groupName' e.g. (Domain\usergroup) but the same throws error when I pass SharePoint groups (SPGroup) name.
Both type of these groups have at least 'Read' permission on site.

I have this code inside 'try-catch' block and hence I am able to catch that thread aborted error.

What could be the reason for this error? I don't get any call stack and all other properties of exception object are either null or with garbage values.

I am having SP2010 foundation, VS2012 and .Net4.5 installed on my machine.

Kindly suggest on this. Thank you.

--
Sagar S.

Comment: Does your application pool account has read access to Active Directory?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, my application pool uses same domain account which has read access to AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the thread below on [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b78cd63f-c686-49d5-bccd-09e7bf26df4a/sputilitygetprincipalsingroup-method-throws-thread-was-being-aborted-error-when-spgroup-name-is?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

The issue was:-
SPWeb & SPSite object was not created within RunWithElevatedPriviledge method.